# Join Server to Worfkgroup Without Creds?

Tags: active-directory, amazon-web-services, powershell, domain

I am imaging servers from stock AMI's in amazon. For business purposes I have to briefly join these servers to the domain so that I can install some agents before I shut them down, sysprep them, and image them as our golden images.

When I try to remove these servers from the domain by joining them to a arbitrary workgroup, I am getting an `Access Denied` error. I am trying to do so by running the following powershell:

`Add-Computer -WorkgroupName 'AWS' -Force`

I have tried doing this by passing random credentials to it as well. It is making me feel like I need credentials for my current domain, to join it to a workgroup.

However... When I go through the Gui to add it to a workgroup, I receive a credential prompt where I can literally give it `Username: 'A' - Password:'A'` and it will join just fine. After a reboot, my server is completely off the domain. I am not even logged in with a domain joined account, it is the local administrator.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Might try `Remove-Computer`

> Remove-Computer  -LocalCredential $cred -WorkgroupName "Workgroup" -Force

Could throw in a -Restart if you want

[Remove-Computer docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-computer?view=powershell-5.1)